# Session graph is empty although graph is set as default

Tags: tensorflow, session

I get the error message that session graph is empty.. I have looked into different questions on stackoverflow page but nothing worked for me..

```py
import os
import sys
import scipy.io
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from PIL import Image
from nst_utils import *
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

model = load_vgg_model("imagenet-vgg-verydeep-19.mat")

tf.reset_default_graph()

# Start interactive session
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

content_image = scipy.misc.imresize(arr = scipy.misc.imread("content.jpeg"), size=(300,400,3))
content_image = reshape_and_normalize_image(content_image)

style_image = scipy.misc.imresize(arr = scipy.misc.imread("monet.jpg"), size=(300,400,3))
style_image = reshape_and_normalize_image(style_image)

generated_image = generate_noise_image(content_image)
imshow(generated_image[0])

# Assign the content image to be the input of the VGG model.  
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(model['input'].assign(content_image))
```

I get "RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run()." Appreciate every advise I can get :)

Comment: Please post a reproducible example so someone can help you.

Comment: Hi, I updated the code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of errors:

1. You are instantiating a model `model = load_vgg_model("imagenet-vgg-verydeep-19.mat")` then reseting the default graph `tf.reset_default_graph()` → it should be the other way around.
2. You have one `tf.InteractiveSession()` started and you are creating another `tf.Session()` → You don't need the first one.

This should work for you:

import os
import sys
import scipy.io
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from PIL import Image
from nst_utils import *
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
model = load_vgg_model("imagenet-vgg-verydeep-19.mat")

content_image = scipy.misc.imresize(arr = scipy.misc.imread("content.jpeg"), size=(300,400,3))
content_image = reshape_and_normalize_image(content_image)

style_image = scipy.misc.imresize(arr = scipy.misc.imread("monet.jpg"), size=(300,400,3))
style_image = reshape_and_normalize_image(style_image)

generated_image = generate_noise_image(content_image)
imshow(generated_image[0])

# Assign the content image to be the input of the VGG model.  
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(model['input'].assign(content_image))
```

Comment: hi! thanks for all the advises, much appreciation! :) if i prefer to have the sess = tf.InteractiveSession() at the beginning, then I wouldnt need the 'with tf.Session() as sess:" statement, right?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your feedback. Yes, you wouldn't need it. Assuming that your other functions are in order, this should work.